# Payment for visa posted by credit card issuer, but government visa website doesn't register the payment

Tags: visas, payment-cards, e-visas, payment, tanzania

I am American and I'm trying to apply for an e-visa to visit Tanzania via official government website. I filled out the application and got the part where I pay. I put in my credit card info and got a message saying that the payment was successful, but then got dropped onto a blank white page that didn't do anything at all (even after waiting for several minutes). While waiting, I checked my credit card and saw that there was indeed an authorization for the right amount.

After I gave up waiting, I closed the tab and re-entered the visa application site. The site has not registered that I paid, and is prompting me to pay again.

Normally, I'd assume that the original transaction just didn't work for whatever reason and the authorization would fall off my card, but after waiting a few days, **the transaction actually posted to my credit card**. It's no longer pending, it's actually posted. The visa site still does not register that I have paid.

I sent a message to the support email address provided on the visa system website with my application ID and issue, and I'll give them some more time to respond. However, assuming I don't hear back from them: what should I do? I suspect I should give up on trying to get an e-visa and just get a visa on arrival. I can contact my credit card and describe the situation to them, but I am worried about them reversing a payment for something official like this. Could it end up causing me issues when I try enter the country?

Comment: As I said in the post: it did actually post - this is no longer a pending transaction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ultimately I never got any response from the Tanzania immigration office about this at all, so I ended up contacting my credit card company and explaining the situation. After sending them some details, they reversed the transaction without much fanfare.

A few months later, I filed a new e-visa application and paid using a different credit card. This e-visa was approved in a few days without any issues, and I had no issues entering Tanzania with the new e-visa letter.

I'll note that it seems that the Tanzania Immigration office switched payment providers between my first and second attempts to pay for an e-visa, so I suspect I was not the only person to have issues.